# REST URI Design : Optional and multivalue information passing

Tags: java, web-services, rest, architecture, jax-rs

I have one search widget where people search for car dealers by zip code. There are also some optional checkboxes to refine search in that widget.

Here is the URI for searching dealer by zip code.

```
http://localhost:8080/dealer/zip/10080
```

If user selects checboxes then the URI will be

```
http://localhost:8080/dealer/zip/10080servicetype=type1&servicetype=type2&servicetype=type3
```

I am using [jersey](http://jersey.java.net). Here is java code.

```
@Path("/dealer")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DealerLocatorRS {
    private DealerService dealerService=new DealerService();

    @GET
    @Path("/zip/{zip}")
    public List<Dealer> getByZip(@PathParam("zip") String zip, 
        @QueryParam("servicetype") List<String> servicetype){
    .. . ..
    }
```

Is this right approach to pass optional and multiple values and . Can anybody help me to apply best practices?

Comment: This looks nice to me. It's possible that your question is a little general. Is there anything specific that you're concerned about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'd map a search for dealers in a particular zip code to a resource; it doesn't feel quite right. Instead, I'd have a resource that lists all the dealers, with individual dealers being sub-resources of that. If it was possible to return a subset of the list of subresources restricted by properties (e.g., their zip code) then that would be a great way to implement a search, otherwise I'd have a separate search handler that returns a list of links to matching dealer resources.

```
@Path("/dealer")
public class Dealers {
    @GET
    public List<Dealer> getAll() { ... }
    @GET
    @Path("search/byZip")
    public List<URI> getByZip(@QueryParam("zip") String zip, ...) { ... }
    @Path("{dealerId:[^/]+}")
    public Dealer getDealer(@PathParam("dealerId") String id) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are serious about understanding and applying REST, I'd recommend reading the [REST paper](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), if you haven't done so yet.

According to the architecture proposed in that paper, Each URL maps to a *resource*.
A resource could be something extrinsic and tangible, like a car dealership.  Or it could be something "virtual" like a "region", or even a zipcode that might contain dealerships.

As to how you parameterize queries, think about what *resource* you want to use to satisfy or expose the queries. Why would you treat "zipcode" as a variable parameter, any differently than, say your "servicetype"?  Are they not both qualifiers to select a subset of dealerships?  Think about why you are making them different - there may be a good reason.

For example, you could do:

- http://server/dealer/zip/10070
  list all dealers in 10070
- http://server/dealer/service/transmissions
  list all dealers that do transmission work
- http://server/dealer/service/transmissions/zip/10070
  list all dealers that do transmission work in zip 10070
- http://server/dealer/zip/10070/service/transmissions
  list all dealers in zip 10070 that do transmission work
- http://server/dealer/service/transmissions/service/lighttrucks
  list all dealers that do transmission work and do light truck service

Think about the mapping of URLs to resources. It may be that two distinct URLs map to the same "result".  you need to decide whether that's appropriate for you.

It's also perfectly fine to retrieve a resource and then do queries on it on the client side. Not all work need be done by the server. You could search through the results obtained by http://server/dealer/zip/10070 on the client side, to find the ones that supply the desired services. This may or may not be a performance win, depending on the size of the data transmitted and the frequency and variety of queries.

Supposing an overall result set of 10 (say, ten dealers within a zipcode), a Javascript foreach loop searching for a dealer that offers service X is going to be faster than an additional AJAX call asking the server to do that query on behalf of the client.

Comment: You seem to be implicitly saying that path parameters would be better than query string parameters to identify resources.  From the perspective of REST this is not the case.  REST doesn't care which you use.  It also appears the service type attributes are not hierarchical in nature, so stuffing them in the path is like putting a square peg in a round hole.  It is important to realize that `http://localhost:8080/dealer/zip/10080?servicetype=type1&servicetype=type2&servicetype=type3` is a different resource than `http://localhost:8080/dealer/zip/10080`.

Comment: @Darrel Miller, I'm fully aware that different URLs refer to different resources. The main thing is to consider why zip should be treated differently than servicetype as a discriminator of dealers, and to consider whether server-side discrimination is even important or appropriate beyond the zipcode.

Comment: Re-reading your answer I see your point.  It's just unfortunate that you chose only path parameters as discriminators.  I would think your last example would be much easier for a server to handle if it was `http://server/dealer?service=transmission&service=lighttrucks`

Answer (score 1):

This is ok, unless your URL becomes too long (although URL length is not limited by any spec, some browsers and intermediaries limit it, so the best practices to keep it under 1K)

If it becomes too long, you may use POST instead of GET.

P.S. You have bug in your code, it should be `@QueryParam("servicetype") List<String> servicetype)` to match the example URI.